# On the integration of a Lebesgue measurable function

Tags: real-analysis, integration, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, supremum-and-infimum

Consider a function $f$ defined as $f:[0,2\pi]\to \mathbb{R}$ such that 
$\begin{equation}
f(x)=\inf_{n\in \mathcal{N}} \sin^2 (2^n x)
\end {equation}$

Is possible to give a decent bound of $\int_{0}^{2\pi} f(x) dx$ or directly get its value?

We can prove that this function is measurable by prove the following lemma:
Lemma: If $\mathcal{F}$ is a family of continuous functions on $[0, 2\pi]$. Then functon $\phi(x)$ defined as $\phi(x)=\inf_{f\in \mathcal{F}} f(x)$
is measurable on $[0, 2\pi]$.

Hence, according to Lusin's theorem we can prove that this function is continuous a.e. on $[0,2\pi]$.

Given all of these, can we get the exact value of the integration if it exists?

Some of my own ideas:

1) I think one of the hard point is to determine the structure of sets $\mathbb{E}_{t}=f^{-1}(t)$ for any given $t$ in the range of $f$.

2) another interpretation on $f$: notice that if we denote $b_{k}= \sin^2 (2^{k} x)$ for fixed $x$ then it's not too hard to check that  $b_{k+1}=4b_{k}(1-b_{k})$. Hence sequence $\{b_{k}(x)\}$ could be regarded as obtained by starting at any point $b_{0}(x)=sin^2(x), x\in [0,2\pi]$ and conduct iteration with respect of $g(x)=4x(1-x)$. $f(x)$ actually measures the infimum of sequence $\{b_{k}(x)\}$ regarding different values of $b_{0}(x), x\in [0,2\pi]$.

Comment: If it's possible, you should always type your question instead of posting it as an image.

Comment: Also, you should tell us what you tried so far and how far you got.

Comment: Ok thanks for your advice, I will add them on soon:)

Comment: $f$ is not continuous. For $x=2 \pi/3 $ we have  $f(x)=3/4$  but $ f(x(1-4^{-k}))=0$  for every positive integer $ k$.

Comment: let $ f_n(x)=inf_{j \leq n} sin^2 (2^j n)$ . Then $ 0 \leq f_{n+1}(x) \leq f_n(x).$..... i suspect that $ f=0$ almost everywhere.

Comment: Just updated the question, see whether this version satisfies the rule:)

Comment: Heuristically, you might expect the numbers $2^nx$ to be essentially "random" mod $2\pi\mathbb{Z}$, at least if $x$ is not a rational multiple of $2\pi$.  So you might expect that with probability $1$, they get arbitrarily close to multiples of $\pi$ and hence $f(x)=0$ almost everywhere.  By examining the binary expansion of $x/2\pi$, you can prove this rigorously.  (I can expand on this in an answer if/when the question is reopened.)

Comment: @EricWofsey thank you a lot, hope to see your expansion on this soon!

Comment: @5xum I have updated my post can it be reopened?

Comment: You cannot conclude from Lusin's theorem that f is continuous a.e. Example: the characteristic function of the rationals is measurable but nowhere continuous.

Comment: Conjecture: For  irrational $x \in (0,1$), let  $L(x)$ be the set of limit points of $ \{ 2^n x-\lfloor 2^n x \rfloor :n \in N \}$. Then $ 0 \in L(x)$. If this conjecture is true then $ f(x)=0$  a.e.

Comment: My conjecture is false  but I can still prove that f=0 a.e.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I claim that $f=0$ almost everywhere.  To prove this, we first need a lemma.

---

**Lemma**: Let $A\subset [0,1]$ be the set of numbers $x$ such that every finite string of $0$s and $1$s appears somewhere in the binary expansion of $x$.  Then $A$ has measure $1$.

*Proof*:  There are only countably many such finite strings, so it suffices to show that for any finite string $s$, the set $A_s\subset[0,1]$ of numbers whose binary expansion contains $s$ as a substring has measure $1$.  Intuitively, this should make sense from a probabilistic perspective: if you think of the binary expansion as being obtained by an infinite sequence of coinflips, you should expect to eventually see any finite sequence with probability $1$.

Let's prove this rigorously.  Let $n$ be the length of $s$.  The set $B_1$ of numbers $x=0.x_1x_2x_3\dots$ such that $x_1x_2\dots x_n\neq s$ (i.e., the first $n$ digits of $x$ are not $s$) has measure $(2^n-1)/2^n$.  The set $B_2$ of numbers $x$ such that $x_1x_2\dots x_n\neq s$ and also $x_{n+1}x_{n+2}\dots x_{2n}\neq s$ has measure $(2^n-1)^2/2^{2n}$.  In general, if $B_k$ is the set of numbers $x$ such that $s$ is not equal to any of the first $k$ disjoint blocks of $n$ digits of $x$, $B_k$ will have measure $(2^n-1)^k/2^{kn}$.  Since $(2^n-1)^k/2^{kn}\to 0$ as $k\to\infty$, the intersection $\bigcap B_k$ must have measure $0$.  But this intersection contains the complement $[0,1]\setminus A_s$, so $A_s$ must have measure $1$.

---

Now let's use the lemma to show $f=0$ almost everywhere.  Given $x\in [0,2\pi]$, let $y=x/2\pi$.  Note that for any $n$, the binary expansion of the fractional part of $2^n y$ is just the binary expansion of $y$ with the first $n$ digits removed.  In particular, if $y\in A$, then the set of fractional parts of numbers of the form $2^n y$ is dense in $[0,1]$ (since any finite string is the start of the fractional part of $2^ny$ for some $n$).  This means that the values of $2^n x$ modulo $2\pi$ are dense in $[0,2\pi]$.  It follows that the values of $\sin^2 (2^n x)$ are dense in $[0,1]$.  In particular, the infimum of such values is $0$.  Thus $f(x)=0$ whenever $y\in A$, and it follows from the lemma that $f(x)=0$ almost everywhere.

Comment: you beat me to it but i do have tp sleep sometimes. ..well written

Comment: @EricWofsey Let $\Lambda$ denote the set of all the finite binary strings that consist of $0$ and $1$. Hence by your definition, $A=\bigcap_{s\in \Lambda} A_{s}$, thus $m(A_{s})=1$ does not suffice to imply that $m(A)=m(\bigcap_{s\in \Lambda} A_{s})=1$.

Comment: @XinHu: $m(A_s)=1$ does imply $m(\bigcap A_s)=1$ when every $A_s$ is a subset of $[0,1]$.  You can see this by letting $C_s=[0,1]\setminus A_s$; then $m(C_s)=0$ for each $s$, so $m(\bigcup C_s)=0$.  But $\bigcap A_s=[0,1]\setminus \bigcup C_s$, so $m(\bigcap A_s)=m([0,1])=1$.

Comment: @EricWofsey thank you a lot understand thoroughly now! Is it also related to normal numbers?

Comment: @XinHu: Yes, it's related.  Normality is an even stronger property which almost every number has (not only does every finite sequence appear in it, but it appears "as often as you would expect by random chance", roughly speaking).

Comment: @EricWofsey Is it possible to prove $\pi$ is a normal number?